# Visual Studio Advanced Query Builder MySql adding "def." before table names

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, xsd, function

From within the .xsd designer I drag a table from a MySql connection on the list and begin  configure it.  When I open the Advanced Query builder, The sql is changed from what was in the initial box

```
select * from x;
```

to

```
select * from def.schema.x
```

where schema is the actual schema and the problem is that I don't see where the def prefix is coming.  MySql version 5.5.8, MySqlConnector 6.3.4, Visual Studio 2008, Windows 7 64.  This same process was working fine on XP.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue.  I am using Visual Studios 2010 on Win 7 64.  MySqlConnector 6.3.1.  What I did was uninstall MySqlConnector/Net 6.3.1 and installed MySqlConnector/Net 6.3.6 and it working fine now.

Comment: I could not install 6.3.6 due to an install bug, but installed 6.3.5 (may have been on that originally) and the problem still exists.

Comment: Years later I run into the problem again when migrating some files between projects. I upgraded the MySql Connector to 6.5.4 and def.schema prefix is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey ,I had this damn problem before but i solved it
All what you need to is :
install .net FrameWork 4.0 before installing the .net connector 6.3.6.**

In Case it did not work install visual studio 2010 and it will work 100%.